# Error with concatenating characters to string in Arduino Server

Tags: arduino

I'm trying to create a server that draws the HTML from the SD card. I'm alternating between two HTM files in the SD card, one is "index.htm" and it has the html code for the unchecked webpage, and the other one "checked.htm" has the code of the checked webpage. However, the problem is this:

the "Serial.print(c);" accurately takes every character taken from client.read, but when I try to concatenate it to HTTP_req, a string, it only gets a tiny portion of it.

Any ideas? I really appreciate any answers because I'm new at this xD!

Code:

```
    #include <SPI.h>
    #include <Ethernet.h>
    #include <SD.h>

    byte mac[] = { 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAB, 0xAD };
    IPAddress ip(10, 20, 7, 75);
    EthernetServer server(80);
    boolean LED_status = 0;
    File webFile;
    String HTTP_req;
    int first = 0;

    void setup() {
      Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
      server.begin();
      Serial.begin(9600);

      Serial.println("Initializing SD card...");
      if(!SD.begin(4)) {
        Serial.println("ERROR - SD card initialization failed!");
        return;
      }
      Serial.println("SUCCESS - SD card initialized.");
      if(!SD.exists("index.htm")) {
        Serial.println("ERROR - Can't find index.htm file!");
        return;
      }
      Serial.println("SUCCESS - Found index.htm file.");
    }

    void loop () {
      EthernetClient client = server.available();
      if(client) {
        Serial.println("Connected to client");
        boolean currentLineIsBlank = true;
        while (client.connected()) {
  if(client.available()) {
    char c = client.read();
    Serial.print(c);
    delay(1);
      HTTP_req = HTTP_req + c;
    delay(5);
    if(c == '\n' && currentLineIsBlank) {
      Serial.println("HTTP_req inside if");
      Serial.println(HTTP_req);
      client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
      client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
      client.println("Connection: close");
      client.println();

      if(first == 0) {
        webFile = SD.open("index.htm");
        Serial.println("First if block: Attempted to open index.htm");
        Serial.print("webFile: ");
        Serial.println(webFile);
        if(webFile) {
          Serial.println("First if block: Successfully opened index.htm");
          while(webFile.available()) {
            client.write(webFile.read());
          }
          webFile.close();
        }
        first++;
      }
      else {
        if (HTTP_req.indexOf("LED2=2") > -1) {
          Serial.println("LED2=2 found");
          if (LED_status) {
            LED_status = 0;
            digitalWrite(2, LOW);
            webFile = SD.open("index.htm");
            Serial.println("Block to turn off led: index.htm attempted");
            if(webFile) {
              Serial.println("index sudo unchecked HTML opened");
              while (webFile.available()) {
                client.write(webFile.read());
              }
              webFile.close();
            }
          }
          else {
            LED_status = 1;
            digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
            webFile = SD.open("checked.htm");
            Serial.println("Block to turn on led: checked.htm attempted");
            if(webFile) {
              Serial.println("Checked HTML opened");
              while (webFile.available()) {
                client.write(webFile.read());
              }
              webFile.close();
            }
          }
        }
        else {
          Serial.println("Not Clicked?");
        }
      }
        Serial.println("This is HTTP_req:");
        Serial.println(HTTP_req);
        HTTP_req = "";
        break;
    }
    if (c == '\n') {
      currentLineIsBlank = true;
    }
    else if (c != '\r') {
      currentLineIsBlank = false;
    }

  }
}
delay(1);
client.stop();
      }
    }
```

Comment: By the way, the delay statements are just debugging attempts; the only one that matters is the one at the very end! :D

Comment: Presuming you are using a uno, it is likely you are running out of ram.  Does the line after Serial.println("This is HTTP_req:"); show the whole string or not?

Read https://learn.adafruit.com/memories-of-an-arduino/optimizing-sram - eg. put F()  around all your strings to move them to flash from sram.

Comment: Also simplify the code to the just the part that is failing.  Once that works you can add back the more complicated stuff.

Comment: Please clarify your code, split it in several functions. It will be easier to read and debug.

Comment: And.. Personally for small devices (such as arduino microcontrollers) I hate using variable size buffers. I prefer allocating a fixed size buffer and then fill it. This way you can't run out of ram, you won't spend a lot of time allocating and freeing memory and you will get a much more stable code

Comment: Wow I got a lot of responses! @TomKeddie, I took your advice and used F() and saved a lot of memory - I can only test the program in my classroom, so I'll do it in an hour. Thanks Ôrel, I will put the webFile part in a separate method.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what a variable size buffers is :P @frarugi87. Is that where I allocate a specific length for a string and filling it? Thanks everyone!

Comment: @Divadi yes. When you write `HTTP_req = HTTP_req + c;` the uC allocates `length(HTTP_req)+1` bytes, copies the original content of `HTTP_req` in, appends c and then frees the old pointer. A lot of work! Instead you can write `char HTTPreqBuff[256];` (for instance, or a bigger one if you really need it) and then track the request length with an index variable: `HTTPreqBuff[index]=c; index++;`. When you need it (in your case when `c=='\n'`) you need to also write the terminator, of course: `HTTPreqBuff[index]='\0';`. When, on the other hand, you need to reset it, you just need to set `index`to 0

Comment: Of course you need to track `index` and be sure that you never make it greater than 255 (the size of the buffer minus the terminator place), and if this happens I suggest you to delete the buffer and warn the user that you run out of memory, discarding the whole buffer..